# How can I connect a Sata DVD drive (5.25) to a Laptop with eSata?

Tags: sata, esata

I have a Bluray DVD drive made for a desktop computer that I want to connect to my laptop via the eSata port (my E6520 laptop only has usb2).  I want to do this the cheapest way possible since it won't actually be used very often.

I can easily find Sata to eSata adapters but I know I also need to provide power to the drive and that's where I'm not sure what to do.  Can I get a Sata to eSata cable and then some sort of stand alone Sata power supply that can plug into the wall?  Just not sure what my options are.

If anyone has any specific item recommendations, or just general things I can search for, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You are going to need an external power supply that provides both 5V and 12V.  BTW requests for recommendations are off topic.

Comment: You are best to buy a USB enclosure for that 5.25 drive.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a cheap SATA/molex power block and then use your SATA-to-eSATA cable.
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just putting the drive in an old Desktop I had sitting in the basement.  Had to pick up a Sata cable and a Molex to Sata power adapter but it was too much hassle to try to find an enclosure and other stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Some Sata to eSata adapters will be powered through the USB port. So you will not need extra wires. I do not have personal recommendations at the moment.

Comment: Does the USB port provide enough power for a DVD drive? USB 3.0 maybe *can* according to spec, but the question is still if it *does*.

Comment: The USB power specifications clearly specify that a single USB2.0 port can deliver a maximum of 500mA worth of current at 5V: that's 2.5 Watts. Any electrical device, including an external DVD drive, must list it's maximum power draw so as long as you're beneath 2.5W you will be fine.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.buildcomputers.net/power-consumption-of-pc-components.html), SATA DVD drives require 15 to 27 Watts (when writing), and 1 to 5 Watts during normal operation. That's a bit more than 2.5W ...

Comment: That is an internal DVD drive, compared to an external DVD drive it cosumes more power and runs much faster. Most external DVD drives run much slower and usually only use 2.5W.

Comment: "Does the USB port provide enough power for a DVD drive?" depends on the drive, I have a usb DVD drive and it works on usb 2.0, but is was made for usb use.